# Texmaker never stops compiling, even simple documents

Tags: compiling, texmaker

Suddenly, Texmaker doesn't end compiling, even simple documents as:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
something
\end{document}
```

I believe this could be related to the settings I am using:

[image]

Have someone any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post your log file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `nonstopmode` instead of `nonstopmod`? I'm not sure if that's the cause though.

Comment: Another guess, try Tools > Clean Up

Comment: Your settings have mistakes, but before attempting to correct them, test your LaTeX installation first. Assume your document is named `test.tex`, open a command window at the same folder of the document and issue the command `pdflatex test.tex` and see if it writes an output file `test.pdf` or not?